# Building Boost 1.66 with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build Boost 1.66 with VS2019, I use the `--toolset=MSVC-14.2` for VS2019.

The build goes well and generates the `vc142` libs as I want. However, when I build my projet on Visual Studio 2019, I get an error that the `vc141` libs cannot be opened eventhough I link to `vc142` in the properties of the project.

I tried with Boost 1.70 and I dont get the error.
Is there a way to keep Boost 1.66 on VS2019 or do I have to move to 1.70?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the wrong platform toolset set for your project.

You can change the platform toolset in Project's Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset.

Change it Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: It is on Visual Studio 2019 and when I check the libs in the linker, it is supposed to look for the `vc142` version of the libs and yet, I still get the error of `vc141` lib not found